# Does our blue sky also scatter UV or just visible blue?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atmospheric-science

I'm wondering if I should wear sunscreen or UV sunglasses when exposed to only blue sky, such as working in a room with large windows that let in a substantial area of blue sky.

Then, I wondered if there's UV from blue sky.

I wear sunscreen if driving long distance in California, but probably because sunshine reflects off the good and turns me pink if no sunscreen, even when not exposed to direct sun.

Comment: Normal windows ([soda-lime glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda%E2%80%93lime_glass)) absorb all but the least energetic (UV-A) UV radiation. [While UV-A radiation can damage the skin an possible cause skin cancer in the long term it does not cause sun burns.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_A#Sunscreen_safety_debate)

Comment: @SebastianRiese To me that seems like you could post that comment as a (very informative!) answer.

Comment: Most of the scattering happens where the atmosphere is dense, i.e. where most of UVC and UVB is already absorbed. So the parts that are going to reach you from all over the sky are a bit of UVB and most of UVA.

Answer (score 6):

The sky is blue because of a phenomena called [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering). Rayleigh scattering occurs whenever radiation of any kind encounters particles (in this case [air molecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth#Composition) such as $\text{N}_2$, $\text{O}_2$, or $\text{CO}_2$) that are much smaller than the wavelength of the radiation. In addition, the shorter the wavelenght, the more light gets scattered by Rayleigh scattering. In fact, the total scattered light is proportional to $1/\lambda^4$, so blue light at 400nm will scatter 16 times as well then red light at 800nm!

For UV light that can get through the atmosphere without being absorbed ([UV-A and UV-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet#Subtypes)), the wavelength is in the range of $280$ to $400\,\text{nm}$, while air molecules are $<1\,\text{nm}$, so air molecules scatter UV just like it does blue light. In fact UV-B light around 280nm will scatter more than 4x as easily as blue at 400nm (for the same reason blue scatters better than red). However, if you're behind a glass window/your windows of your car are rolled up, the glass acts as a sublock as [~90% of the light below 300nm (UV-B which causes sunburns) will be blocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet#Blockers,_absorbers,_and_windows), so wearing sunscreen is not as important as when you are outside in the sun.

Comment: The answer is correct but there is something off introduced by the last line in conjuction with the underlying question. In the sense that being outside more scattering means less radiation reaching OP. I think OP cares of just the scattered part. You are correct, but yet, isn't scattering anymore OP should be afraid *when outside*. Beside this, plus one.